# How decrement each column in ArrayList and create new column with the sum of decremented columns in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to come up with a new algorithm for Bulgarian Solitare. On the internet, there is just one solution for this game and everybody just copping it. Here I'm trying to do in a little bit different way. This is the description

> In this assignment, you will model the game of Bulgarian Solitaire. The game starts with 45 cards. Randomly divide them into some number of piles. For example, you might start with piles of size 20, 5, 1, 9, and 10. In each round, you take one card from each pile, forming a new pile with these cards. For example, the sample starting configuration would be transformed into piles of size 19, 4, 8, 10, and 5. The solitaire is over when the piles have size 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, in some order. ( It can be shown that you always end up with such a configuration.) In your program, produce a random starting configuration and print it. Then keep applying the solitaire step and print the result. Stop when the solitaire final configuration is reached.

So what I did I created 2 Dimensional ArrayList and populate it with a random number of piles. Each pile has some amount cards. The sum is exactly 45.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class BulgarianSolitare {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int numberOfCards = 45;
        Random random = new Random();
        int numberOfPiles = random.nextInt(numberOfCards) + 1;
        System.out.println("Number of piles - " + numberOfPiles);

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> piles = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> eachPile = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> lastPile = new ArrayList();


        if (numberOfCards % numberOfPiles != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPiles; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfCards / numberOfPiles; j++) {
                eachPile.add(j);
                }
                piles.add(eachPile);
                eachPile = new ArrayList();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCards % numberOfPiles; i++) {
                lastPile.add(i + 1);
            }
            piles.add(lastPile);
            eachPile = new ArrayList();


        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPiles; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfCards / numberOfPiles; j++) {
                    eachPile.add(j);

                }
                piles.add(eachPile);
                eachPile = new ArrayList();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("This is your beginning set up:");
        for (int i = 0; i < piles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + piles.get(i).size() + "]");

        }   
    }
}
```

The output for this program is.

> Number of piles - 17
>
> This is your beginning set up:
>
> [2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][11]

Now I need to write the main logic of the program, but whatever I'm writing I get an out ob bounds error. Can somebody help me with the alghoritm of this game.

Comment: If I understood you, this game has nothing with the actual cards (regarding the suite or rank). Each pile may be formed from the beans or white papers? I mean some rules you didn't explained at all...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what is inside.

Comment: But... Let's suppose that your number of piles is 45 (it could be considering your code), so each pile have one element. What is the rule about picking an element from each pile? Really, you cannot expect from this community to be familiar with the rules of Bulgarian solitaire. Do you think we should search the internet just to be informed about this game?

Comment: @zlakad This is the fundamental example for CS student so I may expect that this community is familiar with the game. Also, I wrote an exact quote from the book regarding the assignment. And answer to your question ins there " In each round, you take one card from each pile, forming a new pile with these cards.".

Comment: I'm sorry, pal, I tried to help you, BUT I AM NOT familiar with this _fundamental_ example for the students. BTW, I understood your last sentence.

Comment: @Tigran, you can use debugger to understand what happens during your algorithm application. Unfortunately, at the moment, your question is simultaneously too broad "whatever I'm writing I get an out ob bounds error" & too specific "somebody help me with the alghoritm of [Bulgarian Solitare]".